# UML relationship of a static call from another class

Tags: uml

I am creating a class diagram but I was wondering if there would be any association between the 2 classes shown below - as far as I understand it, for association, ClassA must have an instance of ClassB which in this case there is not, however, it does need to know about a variable of ClassB, so is there an association between these 2 classes?

```
public class ClassA()
{
    int val = ClassB.x
}

public class ClassB()
{
    public static int x = 5;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sure there is association. You can't use ClassA without existing of ClassB.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is an association between these two classes. The association is neither an aggregation nor a composition, it is a "uses/usage" dependency.

```
ClassA ------Uses-----> ClassB
```

Take a look at this [link](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rtnlhelp/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xtools.modeler.doc/topics/cdepend.html) to know more about different types of dependencies

Comment: Link seems broken to me, just links to the start page of the IBM knowledge base. How about this link: http://www.uml-diagrams.org/dependency.html